# Why is data received different than data sent through sockets?

Tags: python, sockets, binary

In my sending program on windows I have the code

```
buffer = bytearray([227,1,99])
i = s.send(buffer)
```

While my recieving code on a raspberry pi has

```
data = self.__conn.recv(self.__BUFFERLIMIT)
```

However when checking out the data that was received on the pi via a debugger, the data received as [343,1C] in hex format, what exactly is going on? As the values of integers don't seem to match up to the hex valeus received.

Note: the windows is running in python 3 and the one in the pi is running in 2.7.

Comment: '343' cannot be a representation of a byte value in ASCII hex.  'FF' is the largest value possible.  What are you doing?

Comment: cos byte != string. So convert to string before send(is very simple).***s.send(str(buffer))***. Or create communication pattern (with struct)

Comment: When looking up in a strace command on the raspberry pi, it said that the network recv command got "\343\1c" when it read the socket and a total of 3 bytes were read.

Comment: \343\1c is a string consisting of three characters: \34, 3 and \1c. However, it should send \e3, \01, c. Something is off, probably in converting between strings and bytearrays, and perhaps also printing. Can you show us you complete code and the exact output? Have you tried a string with normal ASCII characters?